# How to attach database from winforms using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have written code to check the database is existed or not and If not existed then I am trying to attach the database from my local directory. My code is:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CENSYS08\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from sys.databases", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

         string[] array = dt
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Name"))
             .ToArray();

        if(!array.Contains("cstmrDB",StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_attach_db");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", "cstmrDB");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename1", @"C:\Naresh WORK AREA\My Projects\AttachDB\Data\cstmrDB.mdf");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

And one more thing, I have gave the permission to my local file as [this](http://sqltrends.blogspot.in/2012/04/attached-failed-unable-to-open-physical.html). Event it is throwing an exception as

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Naresh WORK AREA\My Projects\AttachDB\Data\cstmrDB.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".

How can I attach my database to sql server.

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk here, but does the file actually exist in that path? `C:\Naresh WORK AREA\My Projects\AttachDB\Data\cstmrDB.mdf`

Comment: yahh.. sure. I copied that file from default location to this location. I have copied the directory from windows explorer address bar.

Comment: and `CENSYS08` is your local machine name?

Comment: I think the Problem is, that the Server is not installed on your local machine. You have to copy your file to the machine (CENSYS08).

Comment: Yes.. CENSYS08 is my local machine name. and I am sure that I have Installed server on my machine. Now I am in my office. We are working on sql 2005. How cannot we be without sql server.

Comment: Is your file marked as readonly?

Comment: No.. There is no readonly option in security permissions. I have allowed all the permissions. Everything is permitted to that file

Comment: Readonly is not a permission, it is an attribute of the file. Right click the file, select properties from the menu. At the bottom of the panel there is a checkbox with the text readonly. This checkbox should be unchecked.

Comment: Yahh.. I have checked the property. It is not checked. Soo The file is not readonly also..

Answer (score 2):

You should remove spaces in your path use '_' like- C:\Naresh_WORK_AREA\My_Projects\AttachDB\Data\cstmrDB.mdf
If still this problem not resolved try following code.
Also you can remove extra step in your code for checking DB name in query.

```
string query = "select name from sys.databases where name='cstmrDB'";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CENSYS08\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query , con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
{
   query=" CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 ON"+ 
   " (FILENAME = 'C:\Naresh_WORK_AREA\My_Projects\AttachDB\Data\cstmrDB.mdf'), "+
   " (FILENAME = 'C:\Naresh_WORK_AREA\My_Projects\AttachDB\Data\cstmrDB.ldf'),"+
       " (FILENAME = 'c:\myFTCatalogs\cstmrDBCat')"+
   " FOR ATTACH;"

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
       cmd.Connection = con;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have also the associated .ldf (log file) file along with the .mdf, otherwise it will throw error

Comment: I think No need.. If yes. How can I attach that too in query

Comment: ldf file is attched by the parameter @filename2. Months ago, that was a big problem for me ,Cauz i'd lost my ldf file. But i dont think that will solve your case because, right now i checked attaching one db without .ldf and ther was no problem. See ldf file is a must for sql server. It tries to build one if does'nt exist. My problem in the past was that the previous location of the database file was been changed, thus causing the .ldf file to get created in the previous location, and mdf in the current..

Comment: So those two in the different locations caused the problem.. Have you changed the location name of your database .mdf file...??